# Camel: getting EndpointUri of a nested route

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have route A that calls route B:

```
from("direct:a")
.to("direct:b");

from("direct:b")
.process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
        {
            System.out.println("Route B URI: " + exchange.getUnitOfWork().getRouteContext().getFrom().getEndpointUri()); //oops, prints direct:a
        }
    });
```

I would like the nested route B to print out its own URI, not the URI of the encapsulating route A. How could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, I don't think it's possible as is.

The UnitOfWorks keep a Stack of RouteContext, but this stack is not publicly accessible. However, you can access a history of the processor in which the exchange has been routed. This collection of `MessageHistory` is located in an header `Exchange.MESSAGE_HISTORY`. It contains the id of the processor and (sanitized) uri of the endpoints.

A more simple/robust approach can be to add explicitly a header on each route invoking the route B.

Personally, I don't think it's a good idea to depend on such information // internal details of the route!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `routeId()` instruction to your route and use that to access your route definition:

```
from("direct:b")
   .routeId("routeB")
   .process(new Processor() { 
          @Override 
           public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception { 
                System.out.println("Route B URI: " + exchange.getContext().getRoute("routeb").getFrom().getEndpointUri());  
           }
    });
```

Comment: If I knew what route I am at (by specifying a certain `routeId`), then I could go ahead and hardcode the EndpointUri. The question is intended for processors that don't know in which routes they may be used. I am trying to get the EndpointUri data from the exchange (probably).

Comment: Sorry,  your question wasn't implying a processor that may be used somewhere else.

Also, what is the purpose of a processor that need to be so "route dependent" without declaring the route implicitly? With more information, we may have a better answer.